# Cant install application

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am able to install an application developed in xcode 5 in ios 7 iphone 4 device but i am getting following error

[image]

Plist info

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What does the error message mean to you?

Comment: You get any warnings or error messages when you compile/run this that are even a bit relevant to this case? (Btw is Resturant in "resturant app" a intentional miss-spelling?)

Comment: My device also have ios 7 then what the other requirements are needed?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus yes because thats not main concern here. No i dont get any warnings or error when i run it on simulator

Comment: It says it's upset about something in Info.plist.  What does that look like?

Comment: @medvedNick sorry thats not working

Comment: I was thinking that iPhone 4 has armv6 architecture, but it has armv7... so it should be ok... why does it call it iPhone 8?

Comment: @medvedNick  Its the number of iphone we have given (just a serial number)

Comment: If you delete the "Required device capabilities" array, does the error go away?

Comment: @PhillipMills no tried that too